# Python: Why does this dictionary change even if I don't access it?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm and I'm running into a very weird issue.

I have the following loop for running the genetic algorithm:

```py
while True:
    # Calc population fitness
    population_fitness, best_individual = self.fitness(pop)
    print(best_individual)
    print(max(population_fitness))
    # Select 50% of population
    selected_population = self.selection(pop, population_fitness)
    # Perform crossover
    new_pop = []
    for i in range(pop_size - 1):
        parent1 = selected_population[randrange(0, len(selected_population))]
        parent2 = selected_population[randrange(0, len(selected_population))]
        child = self.crossover(parent1, parent2)
        # Perform mutation
        if randrange(0, 100) > 92:
            child = self.mutation(child)
        new_pop.append(child)
    new_pop.append(best_individual)
    pop = new_pop
    print(pop[-1])
```

My goal is to keep the best individual from the population, and always copy that to the next population. The best individual is returned by the fitness function. The individuals are OrderedDicts containing some values I try to optimize. What I just don't get is that the the print statement in the fourth line returns a different dictionary to the print statement in the last line. I was thinking it might have to do something with the OrderedDict since I never used those before. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post [mre].

Comment: `pop = new_pop` doesn't make a copy. You just gave the object `new_pop` an additional name.

Comment: @Matthias And? Did they say it makes a copy?

Comment: Perhaps your `crossover` is mutating one of the parents, and `best_individual` is sometimes a parent. Without a [mcve] we can  do no more than guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print `best_individual` at the start of the loop. At the end of the loop you append it to the list and print the last element. The output of the print statements is not the same.

They should be the same object, so if they're printing differently it means the object has been altered. Do any of the methods you've called alter any of the individuals in place (by reassigning keys)? I assume that the `best_individual` is included in the `selected_population` since you're apparently selecting 50% of the population based on the fitness information. So if `self.crossover` or `self.mutation` assign keys on the objects that are passed in as arguments (`parent1`, `parent2`, and `child`), then you could be accidentally altering the `best_individual`.

You might think that if `child` is a new object then whatever is done to it in `self.mutation(child)` couldn't possibly be altering `best_individual`, but there's a potential gotcha I can guess at. You might accidentally be introducing aliasing between the parameters of the individuals. For example, if `self.crossover(parent1, parent2)` is creating a new individual by randomly choosing each of its key values from either `parent1` or `parent2`, then the values in the new child will be the exact same objects as in the parent. If some of those values are mutable objects (like lists) and they are then altered in place in `self.mutation(child)` (instead of assigning *new* values for the keys), then when you mutate a child you'll also be mutating one of the parents, which could have been `best_individual`.

If it's not obviously one of those things, some of this code must still be altering `best_individual` somehow (If `pop` comes from a instance variable on whatever this class is that you haven't shown us and its contents are aliased rather than copies, then any method at all could potentially be getting into wherever the `pop` came from and altering some of the individuals there, one of which is `best_individual`). Rather than staring at the code and guessing (or asking other people on the internet to stare at only a part of the code and guess), you should try to narrow down *exactly* where the `best_individual` is altered. If you know how to use the debugger, that's your best bet. If not (and you don't feel like learning now), just insert `print("1: ", best_individual)` statements between every single line (change the numbers so you can tell where each print output came from). That should at least tell you the call where `best_individual` first changed; then you look inside the code of that and see what was happening there.

Comment: Thank you so much! Although I still not fully understand why, it is indeed the problem you described in the third paragraph. Using a copy of the parents instead of the parents inside the crossover function fixed my issue.

Comment: @Henkie Aliasing mutable objects (when two different objects have references to the same object in one of their properties) is an *extremely* rich source of bugs. Essentially, you need to either be very careful when you mutate an object that it could not possibly be referred to anywhere else (e.g. know that you just created it), or be very careful when you assign properties that the object could not possibly be referred to anywhere else (e.g. because you copy it first and only assign the copy). You can't afford to be laissez faire about both.

Comment: @Henkie I suspect you should take another look; I think the right place for making copies will be in the code of `self.mutation` (copy the object you assign for each key, rather than copying both entire parents before you call). If making copies of the parents fixed the issue, then it means that `self.crossover` is creating children whose attributes alias other objects. If you can fix it in there, then it won't matter how you call it; if you only fix it by copying the parents first, you have to remember to *always* do that every time you call this method (and it'll be a bit less efficient).